# Как можно убрать задержку при передаче команд на дрон Tello? Python

Tags: python

столкнулся с такой проблемой: при передачи команд по сокету на устройство-дрон DJI Tello устанавливается задержка между передачами команд. В программном коде это вызвано функцией time.sleep(...). Пытался убирать её, но программа начинает ругаться.
Дело в том, что существует приложение на устройства Android для управления этим дроном, и там такой задержки при тех же основных командах вверх или вниз нету. Хотелось бы узнать, как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Нам нужно увидеть код откуда вы убрали time.sleep(...) и сообщения об ошибках, которые после этого появились.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Добавьте код с пояснением в сам вопрос, чтобы было от чего помогать

Comment: Можно попробовать просто уменьшить задержку для начала